# RaspberryPI 400: Where is the @ and the € symbol on the German version?

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

On a German RaspberryPI 400 with Raspbian OS also set to German: What are the keyboard shortcuts for the `@` and the `€` characters?

Comment: Normally, a german keyboard should have the € at `AltGr+E` and the @ at `AltGr+Q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the official [Raspberry Pi 400 product brief description](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pi400/pi400-product-brief.pdf) on page 5 on the bottom you will find the keyboard layout for german.
You will have to press and hold the right 'Alt'-Key. The left 'Alt'-Key will not work. (I really hate this.)
So as @PMF wrote you will have to press Q or E in combination with the right 'Alt'-Key to get @ or € accordingly.